# Is it worth replace the engine of an 11 year old fridge

Tags: repair, kitchens, refrigerator, engine

I have an 11 years old fridge that stopped freezing/cooling. I asked for a quote to fix it.

My consideration is if it's better to fix the engine or to buy a new one. I would like to know if in an 11 years old fridge I'll possibly have more issues soon or usually the fridge will work well for a while?

Comment: What do you man by "engine"? Motor?  Compressor? Electrical problem? Coolant leak? Icing problem? ... Remember that replacing an old fridge may save enough energy to affect the answer.

Comment: VTC because this question is looking for product service recommendations which is off topic here.

Comment: It's almost certainly cheaper/better to buy a whole new fridge.

Comment: "engine" in the abstract sense of "greater machine", a la "search engine" or "engine of the world".    NO.  Total waste of time.  New fridges are more efficient and the power savings will pay for the new fridge.

Comment: Without knowing the exact parts being replaced, the cost of this repair, the local costs of a replacement fridge, the local cost to operate the fridge, and the efficiency differences between the two fridges, this question is impossible to answer.  Even with all that information, this is more of an economics question, than a diy home improvement one.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your refrigerator is designed to be repaired, that is a drastic repair, and it's almost certainly going to be a better choice to buy a whole new one:

- Consumer fridges are designed to be assembled once, and never disassembled. There are probably plenty of pipes and wires that are glued in place and/or buried inside the structure, and are almost impossible to remove without destroying something else
- You think you know what's wrong with the unit, but after you've spent a lot of money you may find that you were wrong, and haven't fixed the real problem
- Even if you do manage to fix this problem, the best you'll get is an 11-year-old fridge that is may fail in some other way at any moment
- Even if the fridge never fails again, it will likely be less efficient and less convenient than a new fridge. Plus, when you choose a new fridge you'll have the chance to get something that better matches your needs.